# Xubuntu 12.10 wifi won't connect to wpa2 enterprise network

Tags: wireless, 12.10, xubuntu, wpa2

I have dual boot win7 and Xubuntu 12.10. The wifi works perfectly in win7, and in Xubuntu except for Wpa2 enterprise encrypted network. I had followed the settings for ca-certificate and other specs but it just won't connect. I don't want to upgrade to 13.10 yet because worried about other bugs and configurations. I was trying to modify the config file as some post suggested to make "true->false" but I don't have that line of code in the profile. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, by a known method from Internet, but with a little bit difference in the content of the config file according to specific release version I guess.

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

sudo sed -i '/ca-cert=/ d' "SSID"
```

replace the

`SSID` with the your SSID, and that's it!

good luck!